# Application.cfm file not executing on Lucee 5.2.8.50

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, lucee

I currently have a legacy ColdFusion application running in my production environment on Lucee 4.5.2018 and a MYSql DB that utilizes Application.cfm files. (Yes I know, I should be using Application.cfc instead)

I have setup a brand new Windows 2016 server running Lucee 5.2.8.50 and MySQL and copied over my webapp files and data dump file. But on this new server, it doesn't seem as though anything is processing in my application.cfm file. I have some basic queries that run against my DB in my application.cfm file and I set some variables to the returned data and none of that is functioning on my new server.

In my production environment, everything works fine. All data and cfm files are exact on both server. Just the lucee and MySql versions are different.

Is there anything I need to do on my new Lucee server to enable legacy Application.cfm files to run correctly?

Thanks
-Brian

Comment: Are you using IIS? If so, make sure you have 3 Boncode Handlers set up. For '\*.cfc', '\*.cfm' & '\*.cfml'...

Comment: I checked and I have the handlers in there for CFC and CFM.Jsut not CFML. But I am not using CFML extensions at all in my application.

Comment: Look to see which "mode" is selected in the Admin screen. Maybe it is set to Application.cfc only? See image in "Location, Location, Location" https://docs.lucee.org/guides/cookbooks/application-context-basic.html

Comment: Are you using a Windows server? Or are you using some other case-sensitive file system, like Unix/Linux? I have had issues before moving to a Linux server with an `application.cfm` file instead of `Application.cfm`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Application.cfc (eg. from the default lucee installation home page) can override your Application.cfm. that was my problem.